Handheld shower head leaking water when another bathroom's water turns on
I have a shower combo (handheld shower with overhead shower) in one of my bathroom. Whenever hot water is turned on from any other room on the same floor, handheld shower head starts dripping water bit by bit. I thought it could be the gasket/cartridge issue as others mentioned in other similar questions, but I find it odd that only handheld shower head is leaking, not the overhead shower. I also find it odd the leak only occurs when hot water is turned on, not cold water. My suspicion is it might just be a faulty handheld shower head/hose because I did replace the hose before. I don't remember if it was leaking prior to the replacement of the hose.
I'm wondering if cartridge, or something else, could still be an issue despite only handheld shower head is leaking? Could this mean it's the handheld showerhead that is the problem?
Edit: Clarifying the question after doing few experiments.

Usually if water is running, the water pressure should be reduced a bit and you would expect any leaking to stop/slow down, not to start.  Would the other bathroom be above this one?  Are you sure the leak is coming from inside that hose or running down the outside?

I should clarify, there is no leak at all when no water is running in any bathrooms on the same floor. I did a quick experiment just now, and I found out that the handheld showerhead starts leaking water only when hot water is turned on from any other bathroom on the same floor. The showerhead at the top of the bathroom never leaks.

@crip659 The leak is coming out from the handheld shower head, not from the hose. Now that I think about it, that's a good point. Maybe hose was never an issue since it's not leaking in between the hose and the shower head. Would this suggest it's maybe faulty shower head?

Shower heads/hoses only have pressurized water in them when the valve is open.  It should be the shower valve that is leaking.  But it should leak more when no water is being used(the highest pressure in the system).  When running water the pressure goes down in the system, making leaks harder/less easy to show.  So it only leaking when running water somewhere else is odd.  Was hoping you had a bathroom above, since water runs down.

check the shower diverter valve

This may or may not be relevant, but most of the flexible hoses to hand-held shower heads have a vacuum breaker at the supply end of the hose. This to prevent backflow through the shower head should the head be immersed in water and the supply pressure would drop (just like what could happen with a hose outside). These vacuum breakers can leak under certain circumstances. However there must be a valve between the hose and the hose plumbing and so it is hard to see how this could occur.

Is the leak just a limited dribble or does it leak continuously as the water is run in this other bathroom? A small amount of water trapped in the flexible hose when the valve is shut off could flow out the vacuum breaker if the hose was full and the shower head placed in the holder with the head above the level of the vacuum breaker.

I realized as I was watching it drip that the trim in this bathroom sets the diverter to handheld shower by default when off, meaning you have to press the knob to divert the water to the overhead shower. When you turn it off, the diverter goes back to handheld shower by default. This means I was wrong about thinking handheld shower is the only thing at fault. My guess now is something is wrong within the trim. Thanks for all your comments! I will update as I work on to figure this out.
